# Browser code editor with read-only blocks

Tags: javascript, editor, codemirror

I am trying to let users edit **html/css** but prevent them from
modifying code in **<?php** block

So far I have been testing [codemirror](https://codemirror.net/) and was able to 
get desired results by using **markText** with read-only paramether.

I was wondering if there is a different way to do it, or different
browser based editor?

Here is my example:

```
htmlEditor.markText({line:4,ch:1},{line:7,ch:1},{readOnly:true});
```

Below is entire code snippet which prevents **<?php** block from editing

```js
window.onload = () => {
 // js syntax
 function init(ok) {
  return ok;
 }
}
var htmlEditor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
 lineNumbers: true,
 mode: "htmlmixed",
 theme: 'default'
});
htmlEditor.markText({line:4,ch:1},{line:7,ch:1},{readOnly:true});
```

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
 height: 100%;
}
html {
 background: #fff;
 text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 letter-spacing: .3px;
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
body {
 color: #151515;
}
html {
 font-family: 'Geneva', sans-serif;
}


/* ----------
 WRAPPERS & CONTAINERS
---------- */
section {
 position: relative;
 padding: 2.5rem 0;
}
.container {
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0 20px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 970px;
}
section:after, .container:after, .row:after {
 display: table;
 content: '';
 clear: both;
}


/* ----------
 ANHOR TAG
---------- */
a {
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: 0;
}
h1 > a,
h2 > a,
h3 > a,
h4 > a,
h5 > a,
h6 > a,
p  > a {
 color: #ed9d0a;
 text-decoration: none;
}
h1 > a:hover,
h2 > a:hover,
h3 > a:hover,
h4 > a:hover,
h5 > a:hover,
h6 > a:hover,
p  > a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}


/* ----------
 TYPOGRAPHY
---------- */
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
ul {
 margin-bottom: 1rem;
 -ms-word-break: break-word;
 -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
 -webkit-word-break: break-word;
 -webkit-word-wrap: break-word;
 word-break: break-word;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
h1:last-child,
h2:last-child,
h3:last-child,
h4:last-child,
h5:last-child,
h6:last-child,
p:last-child,
blockquote:last-child,
ul:last-child {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
 line-height: 1.25em;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-weight: 600;
}
h1:not(:first-child),
h2:not(:first-child),
h3:not(:first-child),
h4:not(:first-child),
h5:not(:first-child),
h6:not(:first-child) {
 margin-top: 1.5em;
}
h1 {
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 font-size: 1.75rem;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 1.5rem;
}
h1 strong,
h2 strong,
h3 strong,
h4 strong,
h5 strong,
h6 strong {
 font-weight: 700;
}
p {
 line-height: 1.5em;
}
ul {
 padding-left: 1.5rem;
}
hr {
 border: 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}


/* ----------
 CODE BLOCK
---------- */
.code-container {
 position: relative;
 margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
.code-container:last-child {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.btn {
 background-color: #ed9d0a;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 4px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: 200ms -webkit-transform ease, 200ms transform ease, 200ms box-shadow ease;
   transition: 200ms -webkit-transform ease, 200ms transform ease, 200ms box-shadow ease;
}
.btn:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);
   transform: translateY(-2px);
}
.btn.btn-left {
 float: left;
}
.btn.btn-right {
 float: right;
}


.row {
 margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
 width: 100%;
}
.row:last-child {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.32.0/codemirror.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.32.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<section>
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Trying to mix HTML and PHP</h1>
<div class="code-container">
 <textarea id="code">
<!-- xml/html syntax -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <?php
   phpinfo();
  ?>
  <!-- meta -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- title -->
  <title>Example website</title>

 </head>
 <body>
  <section>
   <div class="container">
    <h1>Example website</h1>
    <p>This is just a HTML example</p>
   </div>
  
  </section>
 </body>
</html>
 </textarea>
</div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Question is really clear: "did anyone solve above problem in a different way?". How more clear could it be? Please feel free to edit my question!

Comment: I have included that line, because I was forced by system, it asked for a peace of code, clearly whole codepen can't be included... Nor other editor used... But let's try that...

Comment: @mplungjan Edited now, but looks much uglier and lost the point...